# My adapter in recyclerview change background color of 2 items instead of 1

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, android-adapter, android-viewholder

I have 10 items like this in recyclerview. My problem is when I click one item I change the background color but for some reason another item changes its background color too. I don't know why this is happening.

For example, if I click the first item and change the color, the item in position 8 also changes its color. I only want the item that I click on to change its color.

[image]

This is my code:

```
 override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: MyViewHolder, position: Int) {
    val titulo = holder.itemView.findViewById(R.id.txt_categoria) as TextView

    titulo.text = categories[position].name_category!!

    holder.itemView.setOnClickListener{

        when{
            textView == null ->{
                textView = holder.itemView.txt_categoria
                textView!!.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.design_categories_project)
                textView!!.setTextColor(Color.WHITE)
                fragmentProyectos.filterProjects(categories[position].id_categorie!!,
                categories[position].name_category!!)
            }
            posClicked != position ->{
                holder.itemView.txt_categoria.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.design_categories_project)
                holder.itemView.txt_categoria.setTextColor(Color.WHITE)

                textView!!.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.design_categories_project_white)
                textView!!.setTextColor((Color.parseColor("#343434")))
                textView = holder.itemView.txt_categoria
                fragmentProyectos.filterProjects(categories[position].id_categorie!!,
                    categories[position].name_category!!)
            }
            else ->{
                textView!!.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.design_categories_project_white)
                textView!!.setTextColor((Color.parseColor("#343434")))
                textView = null
                fragmentProyectos.getData()
            }
        }

        posClicked = position
    }
}
```

Comment: Are you sure the item 8 is not the same as item 1? Maybe there is a mix of position.
To solve that, you could replace position by adapterposition. Maybe it will work.

Answer (score 0):

Try setting the color like this:

```
titulo.setTextColor((Color.parseColor("#343434")))
```